# Is fibre product of varieties irreducible (integral)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $X,Y$ varieties (i.e. integral, separated schemes of finite type over $k$). Is the fibre product $X \times_k Y$ necessary irreducible or integral?

I have another more or less related question:

> If $A,B$ are finitely generated $k$-algebras which are also integral domains, is $A \otimes_k B$ an integral domain?

Comment: In addition to the ways below, another way to prove irreducibility is suggested in Ravi Vakil's FOAG:


9.5.L. EASY EXERCISE.:   Show that a scheme $X$ is irreducible if and only if there exists an open cover $X = \cup U_i$ with $U_i$ irreducible for all i, and $U_i \cap U_j \neq ∅$ for all i, j.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

a) Yes, the product $X\times_k Y$ of two varieties over an algebraically closed  field $k$ is a variety. To prove it, reduce to affine varieties and for those  use:

b)   If the field $k$ is algebraically closed and if $A$ and $B$ are $k$-algebras without zero divisors, then their tensor product  $A\otimes_kB$ also has no zero divisors.
 (Whether $A$ or $B$ is finitely generated is  irrelevant.)
This is proved in Iitaka's *Algebraic Geometry*, page 97 (Lemma 1.54)

**Edit: And if $k$ is not algebraically closed...**
... all is not lost!

Let $k$ be a field and $R$ be a $k$-algebra which is a domain and  with fraction field $K$.
If the extension $k\to K$ is separable and if $k$ is algebrically closed in $K$, then for all $k$-algebras $S$ which are domains, the $k$-algebra $R\otimes_k S$ will be  a domain.
(Beware that separable means universally reduced. If $k\to K$ is algebraic, separability coincides with the usual notion.)
With luck, one of $A$ or $B$ may play the role of $R$ and $A\otimes_k B$ will be a domain.

As an illustration,  any intermediate ring  $k\subset R\subset k(T_1,\cdots,T_n)$ (where the $T_i$'s are indeterminates) satisfies the conditions above and will remain a  domain when tensorized with a domain.

**Bibliography**
For the product of algebraic varieties I recommend Chapter 4 of [Milne's online notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ag.html).
For the tensor product of fields, you might look at Bourbaki's *Algebra*, Chapter V, §17.

**New Edit**
At Li's request I'll show that $X\times Y$ is irreducible.
Let $$X\times Y=F_1\cup F_2$$ with $F_i$ closed and consider the sets $X_i=\lbrace x\in X\mid \lbrace x \rbrace\times Y\subset F_i\rbrace$.
Since $$\lbrace x \rbrace\times Y=[(\lbrace x \rbrace\times Y)\cap F_1]\cup  [(\lbrace x \rbrace\times Y)\cap F_2]$$ we see, by irreducibility of $\lbrace x \rbrace\times Y$ (isomorphic to $Y$),  that each vertical fiber $\lbrace x \rbrace\times Y$ is completely included in (at least) one of the $F_i$'s. In other words, $$X=X_1 \cup X_2.$$   It suffices now  to show that the $X_i$'s are closed, because by irreducibility of $X$ we will then have $X_1=X$ (say) and thus $X\times Y=F_1$: this will prove that indeed $X\times Y$ is irreducible.
Closedness of $X_i$ is proved as follows:
Choose a point $y_0\in Y$. The intersection $(X\times \lbrace y_0 \rbrace)\cap F_i$ is closed in $X\times \lbrace y_0 \rbrace$ and is sent to $X_i$ by the isomorphism $X\times \lbrace y_0 \rbrace \stackrel {\cong}{\to}X$. Hence $X_i\subset X$ is closed. qed.

Comment: Could you please say something more about showing $X \times Y$ is irreducible by reducing to the affine case? I could not figur out how to do that.

Comment: Dear Li, that part is purely topological: I have added a new edit giving  a detailed proof.

Comment: Dear @Georges Elencwajg, a typo, $\{x\}\times F_i$ should be $F_i$.

Comment: Dear @wxu, I have corrected the typo. Thank you very much for your attentive reading.

Comment: Dear @Georges Elencwajg, I got it! Thank you so much, I cannot appreciate more!

Comment: Dear Li: you are right, my proof was not complete and I have modified it. Thanks for your attentive reading. Notice however  that I had not written, have never written and will  never  write that  the projection of a product onto  a factor is closed (unless the other factor is complete) : I am too scared that  the hyperbola $xy=1$ (which is an old acquaintance of mine ) would come and bite me!

Comment: I fully understand it now. I appreciate your constant help very much!

Comment: Dear Li, thank you very much: nothing is more pleasant than being read by a user mercilessly  checking details (and pointing to insuficient arguments!)  and yet showing   appreciation .

Comment: It is not clear to me why $(X\times \{y_0\})\cap F_i$ gets sent to $X_i$. Could you elaborate on this step? (It seems to me that we only get that the image contains $X_i$)

Comment: @E.O. you can take the intersect of all the images as you vary $y_0$ to obtain $X_i$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg , by $\lbrace x \rbrace\times Y$ do you mean the scheme theoretic fiber of $X\times Y$ over x? If so are you sure it's homeomorphic to Y? E.g. if X and Y are spectra of fields whose tensor product is not a field then it is false for reasons of cardinality.  But maybe you make use of the algebraically closed condition?

Comment: Also I just want to remark that another way to prove irreducibility (following the local calculation you've explained) is suggested in Ravi Vakil's FOAG:


9.5.L. EASY EXERCISE.:   Show that a scheme $X$ is irreducible if and only if there exists an open cover $X = \cup U_i$ with $U_i$ irreducible for all i, and $U_i \cap U_j \neq ∅$ for all i, j.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Where do you use the "affine case" in your topological proof?

Comment: @Jérémy Blanc The topological proof doesn't use the affine case but it supposes that you already know that $X \times_k Y$ is a variety, which is the non-trivial part that requires the affine case.  I have also used implicitly the fact that the underlying set of the product is the product of the underlying sets. This is certainly false in a more general context: think of $ \operatorname {Spec} \mathbb C \times_\mathbb R \operatorname {Spec} \mathbb C $ which has two points although the factors are singleton sets.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by Georges Elencwajg, the fiber product is also integral if $k$ is algebraically closed. In general, some author require a variety over any field $k$ should be geometrically integral. In this way the fiber product of varieties is also variety. As for the affine case, I just want to mention an example that $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ is not a domain. In fact it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That example helps me clarify initially uncorrect image of fibre product.